# SQLite "Malformed database schema" error

Tags: delphi, sqlite, firedac

I am getting an error while using FireDAC with Delphi. I need help to resolve this. I replaced the SQLite library, but no luck.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
  str_: string;
  rsQ: TFDQuery;
begin

  FDConnection1 := TFDConnection.Create(nil);

  with FDConnection1 do
  begin
    DriverName := 'SQLite';
    str_ := GetCurrentDir+'\SyncData.sqlite3';
    Params.Database := str_;
    Open;
  end;

  rsQ := TFDQuery.Create(Nil);
  rsQ.Connection := FDConnection1;

  rsQ.SQL.Clear;
  rsQ.SQL.Add('update metas set base_version = -1 where metahandle=1');
  rsQ.ExecSQL;

  Try
    if rsQ <> nil then
    begin
      rsQ.Close;
      rsQ.Free;
      rsQ := Nil;
    end;
  except
  end;

  Try
    if FDConnection1 <> Nil then
    begin
      FDConnection1.Close;
      FDConnection1.Free;
    end;
  except
  End;

end;
```

> SQLITE Error "[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: malformed database schema (MmapStatus) - near "(": syntax error."

Comment: I doubt this has something to do with Delphi or FireDAC. You have broken the database (maybe was encrypted or so).

Comment: The SQLite library might still be too old. What is returned when executing `SELECT sqlite_version()` in your program? What is the table definition of `MmapStatus`?

Comment: I am able to open the db and browse the data in SQLite Browser

Comment: So the version of the SQLite client library matches to the one of SQLite Browser (make sure you've linked it properly)? Did you encrypt your database (not likely, but still)?

Comment: the db is not encrypted.

Comment: Right, so then? Have you checked that the lib versions match (running `SELECT sqlite_version()` in your application and that tool)? Keep in mind we cannot help here. You have the database, we don't (my quick test performed well; Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and SQLite Browser 3.10.1).

Answer (score 0):

I was using Python when I got this. I had tried to use some code I had developed in python3.7 in python3.5. The versions were out of sync. I regen'd the project in 37 and it worked fine, no schema issues.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is very sensitive to the version. Also I faced with the same problem after an upgrade of Delphi. First I thought that something is changed in the DB handling in the new version and this causes the problem, but later I found out that a newer version of sqlite3.dll is in the 'bin' directory of Delphi, and this is the cause. I replaced it by the version I have used until then, and the problem disappeared.